# "consumers" referring to "pupils"

Tags: metaphors, literary-device

In the following sentence, "consumers" means "consumers of education." Is this a metaphor, or an ordinary use of the word?

> Education Ministers ought to have placed the interests of **consumers**—that
> is to say pupils—first.

Comment: I have heard 'students & parents' being referred to as customers, but consumers....? Not sure.

Comment: Seems like an ordinary use of the word. Students consume education services.

Comment: The writer is making a point that the pupils and/or students are the consumers of the 'product' of the education system. It's quite common, particularly in extreme free-market political circles, to express everything in commercial (or pseudo-commercial) terms. It would be interesting to know the source of the quote.

Comment: @BoldBen It's an example sentence from a dictionary. If the expression treats education as a commodity, is it a metaphor?